# How to test if object is a vector

Tags: r, object, vector

How to test if an object is a vector, i.e. mode `logical`, `numeric`, `complex` or `character`? The problem with `is.vector` is that it also returns `TRUE` for lists and perhaps other types:

```
> is.vector(list())
[1] TRUE
```

I want to know if it is a vector of primitive types. Is there a native method for this, or do I have to go by storage mode?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are only primitive functions, so I assume you want to know if the vector is one of the atomic types. If you want to know if an object is atomic, use `is.atomic`.

```
is.atomic(logical())
is.atomic(integer())
is.atomic(numeric())
is.atomic(complex())
is.atomic(character())
is.atomic(raw())
is.atomic(NULL)
is.atomic(list())        # is.vector==TRUE
is.atomic(expression())  # is.vector==TRUE
is.atomic(pairlist())    # potential "gotcha": pairlist() returns NULL
is.atomic(pairlist(1))   # is.vector==FALSE
```

If you're only interested in the subset of the atomic types that you mention, it would be better to test for them explicitly:

```
mode(foo) %in% c("logical","numeric","complex","character")
```

Comment: and perhaps `! is.recursive( list() )` for atomicity?

Comment: Except that factor variables will be considered to be `%in% "numeric"` since their mode is "integer". SimonO101's test is needed.

Comment: About the "gotcha", note that `identical(NULL, pairlist())`

Comment: Got here again after finding out that is.atomic() also returns TRUE for a matrix. Which is to be expected, but something I keep on forgetting...

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps not the optimal, but it will do the work: check if the variable is a vector AND if it's not a list. Then you'll bypass the `is.vector` result:

```
if(is.vector(someVector) & !is.list(someVector)) { 
  do something with the vector 
}
```

Comment: This trick helps you get around the fact that R's is.vector function always returns TRUE for both vectors and list.  You have to ask it two questions, that it IS a vector, and that it IS NOT a list.  Although this behavior may change in future versions of R when these bugs get fixed.

Comment: @Jason that's because c(list(), list()) doesn't return an atomic vector but a list. c() doesn't create vectors, it combines elements.

Comment: Thanks @JorisMeys. Another "aha" moment with R. Deleting my comment, as it's misleading.

Answer (score 3):

To check that an object `obj` is a vector, but not a list or matrix, consider:

```
is.vector(obj) && is.atomic(obj)
```

Using only `is.vector(obj)` returns `TRUE` for lists but not for matrices; and `is.atomic(obj)` returns `TRUE` for matrices but not for lists. Here are some sample checks:

```
mymatrix <- matrix()
mylist <- list()
myvec <- c("a", "b", "c")
is.vector(mymatrix) && is.atomic(mymatrix) # FALSE
is.vector(mylist) && is.atomic(mylist) # FALSE
is.vector(myvec) && is.atomic(myvec) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `mode` is to use `class`:

```
class(foo) %in% c("character", "complex", "integer", "logical", "numeric")
```

This would prevent matching lists as well as factors and matrices. Note the explicit listing of integer, since as a class it won't match with numeric. Just wrap that in a little function, if you need to use it more often.