# Basic problem with different types of data

Tags: r, database

I want to write a very simple function. If I put vector in output I should get 'A', if matrix 'B' and if list 'C'. I wrote :

```
check<-function(x){
  if (is.numeric(x)){'A'}
  else if (is.matrix(x)){'B'}
  else if (is.list(x)){'C'}
}
```

And it's wrong function because :

```
Mat<-rnorm(rnorm(4),2,2)
check(Mat)
'A'
```

The reason is clear when we use code :

```
is.numeric(Mat)
```

But me question is : how can I change my function to work properly ? I do not have idea how can I do it

Comment: This may help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501186/how-to-test-if-object-is-a-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `inherits`:

```
check<-function(x){
  if (inherits(x, 'numeric')){'A'}
  else if (inherits(x, 'matrix')){'B'}
  else if (inherits(x, 'list')){'C'}
}
check(numeric(1))            # "A"
check(matrix(1))             # "B"
check(list(1))               # "C"

# Using something else (e.g. data.frame) returns null
(check(data.frame(1)))         # NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems. Firstly, you have passed to your function a 1 dimensional vector, not a matrix:

```
Mat = rnorm(rnorm(4),2,2)
> is.vector(Mat)
[1] TRUE
```

A matrix in R is a 2 dimensional vector:

Secondly, something can both be a numeric type and a matrix object:

```
Mat = as.matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3)

> is.numeric(Mat)
[1] TRUE

> is.numeric(Mat)
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to check whether you have a list, vector or matrix, you should change your function:

```
check = function(x){
  if (is.atomic(x) & !is.matrix(x)){'A'}
  else if (is.matrix(x)){'B'}
  else if (is.list(x)){'C'}
}


> a = rnorm(9)
> check(a)
[1] "A"
> a = matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3)
> check(a)
[1] "B"
> a = list(rnorm(9))
> check(a)
[1] "C"
```

Comment: For me check(list(1,2,3))='A' after implementing your solution

Comment: I've amended the function. The issue is that list types are non atomic vectors - so to check if something is a vector, you need to check that it's atomic, but not a matrix.