# Check for vector and matrix data type at once

Tags: r, matrix, vector

i was wondering if there is as faster way to check if given data is a vector or a matrix with zero rows or not, rather than,

```
if (is.vector(x)){
    print('vector')
} else if {nrow(x) == 0){
    print('0 rows')
} else {
    print('matrix').
}
```

I am only interested in finding matrices fast.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide some example input and output for what you are doing?

Comment: In R, lists are vectors but not *atomic* vectors. And matrices are also atomic but they are not vectors. Do you want the code to return `TRUE` for lists?

Comment: See if [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501186/how-to-test-if-object-is-a-vector) can help.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use `dim`:

```
!is.null(dim(x)) && all(dim(x)>0)
```

If `x` is a vector, `dim(x)` is `NULL`.

I am not sure if this is faster than your own method and also not sure if this is a computation-intensive task at all.